# Can someone tell me what is wrong on my code in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, database, erd

I have attached the ER diagram below.

I'm trying to create a table and schema but I can't because I have an error and can't create a relationship based on the diagram.  I hope someone can look at this.

Thank you.

```
CREATE DATABASE [HOSPITAL]

CREATE TABLE [PERSONNEL]
(
    [Employee no] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [VARCHAR] (50),
    [Gender] [VARCHAR] (60),
    [Address] [VARCHAR] (50),
    [Role] [VARCHAR] (10),
    [Salary] [numeric] (10,2),
)

CREATE TABLE [PHYSICIAN]
(
    [Employee no] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Specialty] [VARCHAR] (30),
    [Rank] [int],
)

CREATE TABLE [SURGEON]
(
    [Employee no] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Specialty] [VARCHAR] (30),
    [Skill] [VARCHAR] (20),
)

CREATE TABLE [MEDICATION]
(
    [Med Code] [VARCHAR] (10) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [VARCHAR] (30) NOT NULL,
    [List Price] [numeric] (10,2),
    [Classification] [VARCHAR] (30),
    [Manufacturer] [VARCHAR] (30),
)

CREATE TABLE [PATIENT]
(
    [Patient no] [VARCHAR] (10) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [VARCHAR] (50),
    [Gender] [VARCHAR] (10),
    [Birthdate] [date],
    [Blood type] [VARCHAR] (10),
    [Blood sugar] [numeric] (10,2),
    [Allergy_code] [VARCHAR] (10),
    [Allergy_name] [VARCHAR] (10),
    [Cholesterol] [numeric] (10,2),
    [Triglyceride] [numeric] (10,2),
    [LDL] [numeric] (5,2),
    [HDL] [numeric] (5,2),
)

CREATE TABLE [PRESCRIPTION]
(
    [Patient no] [VARCHAR] (10),
    [Med Code] [VARCHAR] (10),
    [Cost] [numeric] (10,2),
)

CREATE TABLE [DO_SURGERY]
(
    [Patient no] [VARCHAR] (10),
    [Theatre] [VARCHAR] (10),
    [Surg_date] [date],
)

CREATE TABLE PHYSICIAN_WRITES_MED
(
    [Employee no] [int],
    [Med Code] [VARCHAR] (10),
    [Dosage] [numeric] (10,2),
)
```

[image]

Comment: Please refer to How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I just edited your post.  In future please don't use all capitals when posting here.

Comment: Don't write "I have an error" and the _not_ post the error. That is in no way useful. Never write 'doesn't work' or 'have an error' without _actually posting the error_. How are you creating your relationship? I don't see any foreign key code there.

Comment: The most obvious thing is the trailing comma on the last field in every table definition. i.e. `[HDL] [numeric] (5,2),` should be `[HDL] [numeric] (5,2)` - remove the trailing comma

Answer (score 0):

enforcing an FK can easily be done via scripts and that part I would leave completely up to you. Besides obvious script error pointed out by Nick Mc top side. See no error and you should be easily able to create your tables. When in doubt create 1 table at a time rather than F5 :D